# Event Hub Premium - Processing Unit estimations

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am just wondering if there is any good way to estimate # of Processing Units required for specific configuration in Event Hub Premium. Assume I know the volume of Data In/Out, number of ingress/egress messages, how can I estimate number of PUs?

I looked at this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas also I found on other page this info

> "1 PU and 1 event hub(100 partitions) can approximately offer core
> capacity of ~5-10 MB/s ingress and 10-20 MB/s egress"

Let's say I have traffic ingress 7MB/s and egress 15MB/s, but does it mean that 1 PU is enough? What about # of messages, consumers, producers, # of event hubs in namespace?, as per the documentation they are also relevant here to estimate size of the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I have traffic ingress 7MB/s and egress 15MB/s, but does it
> mean that 1 PU is enough?

Yes, that's correct.

A namespace is a scoping container for Event Hub/Kafka Topics. Calculate the size associated with each namespace (including consumer, producer, message, etc.) and on the basis of that you can choose number of PUs.

[image]

Check the detailed EventHub Premium pricing [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/event-hubs/).

When you create a `Namespace` in EventHub using Portal, you will be responsible to calculate the size of ingress/egress including producers, messages and consumer, and if the total size within the capacity of 1 PU in Premium, you are good to go. Refer below image.

[image]

Similarly you can create multiple Namespaces.

Also, for a premium Event Hubs namespace, the Auto-Inflate feature is automatically enabled. You can't disable it.

**The Auto-inflate feature of Event Hubs automatically scales up by increasing the number of TUs, to meet usage needs.**

So, you don't need to worry much about PU in Premium namespace.

Comment: can you please share documentation link on auto-inflate in 'premium' event hubs?